# Speeding Up Load Time in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, polymer, phonegap-build

I'm making an app using phonegap build, and it takes quite a long time to load. On start-up, it shows a black screen for a few seconds, then my site's background color for a few more, and then actually loads the full page.

The app is built using polymer and jquery, and I'm curious if anybody has tips on making the loading time go down in general. (Showing a loading Icon would also be an alternative, I just haven't figured out if there's a way to do that, even on the black on start-up.)

**Update: Here's the code of my index.html.**

`

```
<head>
    <title>Argon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/CustomElements.js"></script>
    <script src="components/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements.html">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#status").hide();
            $("#post").hide();
            $("#reply").hide();
            $("#settings").hide();
            $(".send").hide();
            $(".save").hide();

        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".home").click(function () {
                $("#reply").slideUp("slow");
                $("#status").slideUp("slow");
                $("#post").slideUp("slow");
                $("#settings").slideUp("slow");
                $(".send").hide();
                $(".save").hide();
                $("#main").slideDown("slow");
                $("#main2").slideDown("slow");
            });
            $(".reply").click(function () {
                $("#main").slideUp("slow");
                $("#main2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#status").slideUp("slow");
                $("#post").slideUp("slow");
                $("#settings").slideUp("slow");
                $(".save").hide();
                $(".send").slideDown();
                $("#reply").show("slow")
                $("#reply").slideDown("slow");
            });
            $(".status").click(function () {
                $("#main").slideUp("slow");
                $("#main2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#reply").slideUp("slow");
                $("#post").slideUp("slow");
                $("#settings").slideUp("slow");
                $(".save").hide();
                $(".send").slideDown();
                $("#status").show("slow")
                $("#status").slideDown("slow");
            });
            $(".post").click(function () {
                $("#main").slideUp("slow");
                $("#main2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#main2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#reply").slideUp("slow");
                $("#status").slideUp("slow");
                $("#settings").slideUp("slow");
                $(".save").hide();
                $(".send").slideDown();
                $("#post").show("slow")
                $("#post").slideDown("slow");
            });
            $(".settings").click(function () {
                $("#main").slideUp("slow");
                $("#main2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#reply").slideUp("slow");
                $("#status").slideUp("slow");
                $("#post").slideUp("slow");
                $(".send").hide();
                $(".save").slideDown();
                $("#settings").show("slow")
                $("#settings").slideDown("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <!--If the icons aren't showing, remove the spaces!-->
    <paper-fab-menu icon="create" closeIcon="close" duration="0.3">
        <paper-fab-menu-item icon="reply" duration="0.3" class="reply"></paper-fab-menu-item>
        <paper-fab-menu-item icon="speaker-notes" duration="0.3" class="status"></paper-fab-menu-item>
        <paper-fab-menu-item icon="note-add" duration="0.3" class="post"></paper-fab-menu-item>
    </paper-fab-menu>

    <core-scroll-header-panel flex fixed="true">

        <core-toolbar>

            <paper-icon-button icon="home" class="home"></paper-icon-button>

            <span flex>Argon</span>

            <paper-icon-button icon="send" class="send"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="save" class="save"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="settings" class="settings"></paper-icon-button>

        </core-toolbar>

        <div id="main">

            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Getting Started With Argon</h1>
                <img src="logos/4000x4000.png" height="15%" width="15%">
                <br>
                <h2>Click the action button on the bottom-right to view posting options.</h2>
                <h3></h3>

            </paper-shadow>

            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Submit Feedback</h1>

                <h2>Tell me what you think!</h2>


                <paper-button>@AveryBMiller</paper-button>


                <br>
                <br>

                <a href=" http://www.averymiller.org ">
                    <paper-button>AveryMiller.org</paper-button>
                </a>
            </paper-shadow>



        </div>
        <div id="main2">
            <paper-shadow class="card " z="2 ">

                <h1>Rate Argon</h1>

                <h2>If you like the app, rate it in the Google Play store!</h2>

                <a href="http://play.google.com ">
                    <paper-button>Rate</paper-button>
                </a>

            </paper-shadow>
        </div>
        <div id="status">
            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Write Status</h1>

                <input type="text">
                <br>
                <br>

            </paper-shadow>
        </div>
        <div id="post">
            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Write Post</h1>

                <input type="text">
                <br>
                <br>




            </paper-shadow>
        </div>
        <div id="reply">
            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Write Reply</h1>

                <input type="text">
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="http://www.averymiller.org">
                <br>
                <br>




            </paper-shadow>
        </div>
        <div id="settings">
            <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">

                <h1>Change Your API Key</h1>

                <input type="text">
                <br>

            </paper-shadow>
        </div>

    </core-scroll-header-panel>


</body>
```

`

Comment: You need to determine and list the resources that your app is loading (and taking time to do so), then assess whether they can be optimised. As it stands you are limiting the answers here as you have provided little.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Sorry about that! ;-) (I added my index.hmtl code to the post!)This is my first phonegap app, and I've tried my best to keep it fast. It runs great on my browser, but it's super slow running on my android phone. The jquery effects (.slideUp, .slideDown) are extremely slow and laggy.

Comment: if your app is intended for mobile use primarily then you might be better to use jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Also, if you use any modern browser's development tools (usually accessed by F12) then you can examine the network tab which will list the resources being accessed and the amount of time taken to download them.

Comment: @AveryMiller, polymer is not yet support with Phonegap. Which is why it is running slow. You MAY want to try the [crosswalk plugin](https://crosswalk-project.org/). It MAY work with that. Again Polymer is tooo new for phonegap. I have not heard of ANYONE getting it running. Polymer is barely supported by a few webbrowswers.